# Changing symmetric.key.master.password not working in 6.0

Tags: java, encryption, sap-commerce-cloud

[Same question](https://experts.hybris.com/questions/75405/view.html)

While installing new `hybris` instance, I trying to changed `symmetric.key.master.password`. But it throw following error while server startup.

**Please note**: I have created `symmetric.key.master.password` with random text/number e.g(`JOSD53FJPjas1243ojdf9872rIJDFOJS3DioaIUOSI64Dj4foiaew12fIIOAS`)

**Error** :

```
  [java] ERROR [main] [EncryptionUtil] pad block corrupted
  [java] javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corruptedWARN  [main] [CloseAwareApplicationContext] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
  [java]     at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JCEBlockCipher.engineDoFinal(Unknown Source)
  [java]     at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165)
  [java]     at de.hybris.platform.util.encryption.EncryptionUtil.loadKey(EncryptionUtil.java:527)
  [java]     at de.hybris.platform.util.encryption.EncryptionUtil.loadKey(EncryptionUtil.java:484)
  [java]     at de.hybris.platform.util.encryption.EncryptionUtil.loadKey(EncryptionUtil.java:429)
  [java]
  [java]     at de.hybris.platform.core.MasterTenant.readKeyFiles(MasterTenant.java:235)
  [java]     at de.hybris.platform.core.MasterTenant.getValueEncryptor(MasterTenant.java:147)
  [java]     at de.hybris.platform.directpersistence.read.DefaultSLDItemDAO.init(DefaultSLDItemDAO.java:69)
  [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
  [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:300)
  [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133)
  [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
  [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566)
  [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
  [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
  [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
  [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
  [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
  [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
  [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
```

**Edit :-**

`local.properties` changes :

```
symmetric.key.file.1=default-128-bit-aes-key.hybris
symmetric.key.file.2=Generated-256-Bit-AES-Key2.hybris
symmetric.key.file.default=2
symmetric.key.master.password=1234567
```

with above configuration hybris server working fine(`hybrisserver.sh`/`ant initialize` etc). But if I try to change `master.password` to `1234568` it throws `pad block corrupted` while `hybrisserver.sh/ant initialize`. I also tried with fresh database(drop/create) and do `ant initialize`, getting same error. It is only working with OOTB `master.password` (`1234567`)

Answer (score 1):

From your stacktrace I think that issue may be with loading your `symmetric.key.file`.

Please try to regenerate symmetric key using recommendations given at [help.hybris.com/Transparent Attribute Encryption (TAE) - Hybris V6](https://help.hybris.com/6.3.0/hcd/8b2c75c886691014bc12b8b532a96f58.html)

Comment: Thanks! yes I have created key file same way... As mentioned [here](https://experts.hybris.com/questions/75405/view.html) I also tried directly changing the `symmetric.password` in `platform/project.property` so `key` will be as is (OOTB).

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to Hybris wiki, see this link it might help you
[Transparent Attribute Encryption](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/SUP/Transparent+Attribute+Encryption)

Comment: I know TAE, already configure it. here I face the problem with master key.